# Cassandra multinode installation,Cannot open file /var/log/cassandra/gc.log due to Permission denied

Tags: remote-access, cassandra

I want to install Cassandra on 4 remote nodes.
Everything works fine until I come to point when I check status

```
nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  103.68 KiB  256          100.0%            4e03d80f-5972-4bc7-b36d-6e536ebfa808  rack1
```

I have properly set listen_address to 
192.68.0.25
and seeds to
192.69.0.13

I got same on the other node

```
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  103.64 KiB  256          100.0%            c7ad74b0-9fa1-4068-a2f8-24e45523b731  rack1
```

This is what I got when I run cassandra from command shell

```
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /var/log/cassandra/gc.log due to Permission denied

18:06:55,305 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.cassandra] to DEBUG
18:06:55,305 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.thinkaurelius.thrift] to ERROR
18:06:55,305 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
18:06:55,305 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@6ea12c19 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

INFO  [main] 2018-01-25 18:06:55,399 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
 Error: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=seed_provider for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@3d36e4cd; java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;  in 'reader', line 10, column 1:
    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
    ^
Invalid yaml: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

Actually I do not have gc.log.This is the content of the folder

```
/var/log/cassandra$ ls *.log
debug.log  system.log
```

And

```
/var/log$ ls -lia cassandra/
total 284
8389155 drwxr-xr-x  2 cassandra cassandra   4096 jan.  25 15:50 .
8257787 drwxrwxr-x 14 root      syslog      4096 jan.  25 15:49 ..
8389157 -rw-r--r--  1 cassandra cassandra 178071 jan.  25 17:50 debug.log
8389086 -rw-r--r--  1 cassandra cassandra  53037 jan.  25 18:16 gc.log.0.current
8389150 -rw-r--r--  1 cassandra cassandra  41003 jan.  25 17:50 system.log
```

Comment: The error message means you have an invalid yaml file, could upload it to pastebin?

Comment: Also check whether the directory can be written by the cassandra user (or whichever you run it from) and when running from command line make sure you run it with sudo, or if you ran it from root, chown the dirs back

Comment: Here https://pastebin.com/LuyejTFL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure, your /etc/hosts file format is valid, such as

```
root@my-cass1-1:~# cat /etc/hosts | egrep -v "^#|::"
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.xxx.13 my-cass1-1.int.xxxxxxxxx.tld my-cass1-1
```

And no localhost.localdomain stuff in it.

in cassandra.yaml set these two options:

```
root@my-cass1-1:~# cat /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml | grep 192.168
          - seeds: "192.168.xxx.111,192.168.xxx.112,192.168.xxx.13,192.168.xxx.10"
listen_address: 192.168.xxx.13
broadcast_rpc_address: 192.168.xxx.13
```

Comment: Ok,will take a look.

Comment: Could you take a look,why is permission denied?